# The tool to deploy per customer EC2 instance

Tags: ansible, terraform

I need to deploy one EC2 instance for each customer. I have hundreds of customer and increasing.

So far, I found Terraform supports count property to provision exact number of instance I need. To do that, I maintain a list of customer, create number of instance to match the length of the list. For example:

- customer_a
- customer_b
- customer_c

Terraform script looks like this:

```
resource aws_instance x {
  count = length(var.customers)

  #...
}
```

It works initially. However, unexpected behaviour happened when I tried to remove customer_b from the list, as a result, customer_c's instance was destroyed and customer_b's instance properties were replaced with customer_c's. What I need is to keep customer_c's instance untouched and destroy customer_b's instance with related resources.

I am not sure if there is better way to do that using Terraform or if there is any other more suitable tools for this use case. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Terraform's `for_each` (available beginning in v0.12.x) can actually accomplish this.

This creates 3 AWS instances:

```
variable "hosts" {
  default = {
    "one" = {
      "name"    = "one",
      "machine" = "t2.micro",
      "ami"     = "ami-009d6802948d06e52",
      "subnet"  = "subnet-002df68a36948517d"
    },
    "two" = {
      "name"    = "two",
      "machine" = "t3.micro",
      "ami"     = "ami-009d6802948d06e52",
      "subnet"  = "subnet-01c13b00a5531828e"
    },
    "three" = {
      "name"    = "three",
      "machine" = "t2.nano",
      "ami"     = "ami-009d6802948d06e52",
      "subnet"  = "subnet-0166523e6bd98ebd8"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "instances" {
  for_each      = var.hosts
  ami           = each.value.ami
  instance_type = each.value.machine
  subnet_id     = each.value.subnet
  tags = {
    Name = each.value.name
  }
}
```

When I comment out `two`, I get the Terraform plan below

```
variable "hosts" {
  default = {
    "one" = {
      "name"    = "one",
      "machine" = "t2.micro",
      "ami"     = "ami-009d6802948d06e52",
      "subnet"  = "subnet-002df68a36948517d"
    },
    # "two" = {
    #   "name"    = "two",
    #   "machine" = "t3.micro",
    #   "ami"     = "ami-009d6802948d06e52",
    #   "subnet"  = "subnet-01c13b00a5531828e"
    # },
    "three" = {
      "name"    = "three",
      "machine" = "t2.nano",
      "ami"     = "ami-009d6802948d06e52",
      "subnet"  = "subnet-0166523e6bd98ebd8"
    }
  }
}
```

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.instances["two"] will be destroyed
  - resource "aws_instance" "instances" {
      - ami                          = "ami-009d6802948d06e52" -> null
      - arn                          = "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXXXX:instance/i-03a8285fc49f48a69" -> null
      - associate_public_ip_address  = true -> null
      - availability_zone            = "us-east-1b" -> null
      - cpu_core_count               = 1 -> null
      - cpu_threads_per_core         = 2 -> null
      - disable_api_termination      = false -> null
      - ebs_optimized                = false -> null
      - get_password_data            = false -> null
      - id                           = "i-03a8285fc49f48a69" -> null
      - instance_state               = "running" -> null
      - instance_type                = "t3.micro" -> null
      - ipv6_address_count           = 0 -> null
      - ipv6_addresses               = [] -> null
      - monitoring                   = false -> null
      - primary_network_interface_id = "eni-05f51ded8af0b5033" -> null
      - private_dns                  = "ip-172-31-36-204.ec2.internal" -> null
      - private_ip                   = "172.31.36.204" -> null
      - security_groups              = [
          - "default",
        ] -> null
      - source_dest_check            = true -> null
      - subnet_id                    = "subnet-01c13b00a5531828e" -> null
      - tags                         = {
          - "Name" = "two"
        } -> null
      - tenancy                      = "default" -> null
      - volume_tags                  = {} -> null
      - vpc_security_group_ids       = [
          - "sg-06aabe12f0a1b34fd",
        ] -> null

      - credit_specification {
          - cpu_credits = "unlimited" -> null
        }

      - root_block_device {
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - encrypted             = false -> null
          - iops                  = 100 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-06ffd6ab6d4e8f671" -> null
          - volume_size           = 8 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Ref: [Terraform Resource For_Each](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/#resource-for_each)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!